# Number in a cell linked with a text

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I would like to ask if there is a solution to my problem:

I have 200 numbers from 1 to 200 which are linked with text. For example: `1 = car, 2 =  bicycle` and so on. I would like to write a number (`1`) in the A2 cell and I would like to automatically get the text (`car`) into the cell B2. Is there some formula for this?

Comment: Yep, you just described the very purpose of VLOOKUP :) would need to see exactly how your data was arranged to give an exact formula.

Comment: Yeah, VLOOKUP is perfect for me :) Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Sheet2!D2:E, 2, 1), ))
```

[image]